# I need help with the "File format not supported in file" Error please

Tags: error, blend-files

I've been working on this blender file for a while now and I wanted to do more work on it. I opened blender but an error showed up when I chose the file I've been working on. It said "file format not supported in file"

Comment: Hi, Liam, We haven't got a lot to go on here. A quick search on the error message turned up [this](https://blenderartists.org/t/file-format-not-supported-in-file-when-opening-blend-file-in-another-pc-same-vers/651348) , for example. Any chance of a corrupt file?

Comment: how would i know if it’s corrupted? i’m pretty new to blender so i’m sorry if it’s easy

Comment: One suggestion in the other post is to try appending items from the file to a new one. Can you open the dodgy file for appending?

Comment: there is nothing in the file